# composer install --dev is gone, how do I use dev dependencies?

Tags: composer-php

1. Most people in my team doesn't need dev dependencies. So it is desirable that `composer install` doesn't install dev dependencies.
2. However, QA does need to install them with some command.

I have no idea how to achieve this now. Formerly it was `composer install --dev` but that's gone.

Comment: "but that's gone" - what does that mean? I've used it just two days ago without problems.

Comment: composer install --dev
You are using the deprecated option "--dev". It has no effect and will break in Composer 3.

Comment: Deprecated does not mean that it's gone already. Also, what does the documentation tell you about this? Maybe you are looing for the options listed at https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i, especially `--dev` and `--no-dev`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `COMPOSER_NO_DEV` to `0` or `1` to change the default behaviour of `composer install` and `composer update`.

see: documentation - [COMPOSER_NO_DEV](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-no-dev)

- If you want `composer install` to **not** install the dev dependencies by default

  - `export COMPOSER_NO_DEV=1`
- If you want `composer install` to install dev dependencies (the default)

  - `export COMPOSER_NO_DEV=0`
  - or `unset COMPOSER_NO_DEV`

Depending on how you develop (i.e. in a container) there are various options to set a default value for the environment variable.

On the other hand you can instruct your engineer colleagues that do not require any dev dependencies to run the command:

```bash
composer install --no-dev

# .. or ..
COMPOSER_NO_DEV=1 composer install
```

... instead of ...

```bash
composer install

# .. or ..
COMPOSER_NO_DEV=0 composer install
```

Comment: Thanks. This was real hard to find, I submitted a PR which got accepted so now the documentation of the `--no-dev` option for all commands links to this environment variable.